# -bash: mongod: command not found even I see mongod in the very directory I am in

Tags: macos, mongodb

I successfully installed MongoDB.  Here's what I see in my bin directory:

$ ls

bsondump    mongodump   mongoimport mongorestore    mongostat
mongo       mongoexport mongooplog  mongos      mongotop
mongod      mongofiles  mongoperf   mongosniff

However, I get:

> -bash: mongod: command not found

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: You likely have not added to `PATH` in the environment and are therefore not executing with `./mongod` in the installed directory nor with the full path to the command `/path/to/mongo/executables/mongod`. It also helps to read an follow the installation guide appropriate to your system ["Install MongoDB on OSX'](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) where if you are not familar with manual installation then you probably should be using the homebrew install instructions.